# Would it be considered good practice to match the lengths of UART's Tx/Rx traces?

Tags: uart, length-matching

I am assuming the answer would be yes since Tx/Rx pins are used to send data back and forth, or is it of such a low frequency that such thing is not required?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Length/impedance matching is used with multiple signals, differential or single-ended, that must arrive at the same point at the same time. Since UART signals are both asynchronous and in opposite directions there is no need to match the traces.

Nonetheless, keeping the traces neat and tidy is an indicator of professionalism even if it is not required.

Comment: What do you mean by "neat and tidy" in your context? Do you mean that we still need to match-length the UART lines even if it's not required?